# Создать DataFrame из вложенного (nested) JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть некоторый JSON файл:

```
[{'id': 1,
   'info': {'somedata': 'spamegg',
            'moredata': 'spameggtoo'}},
  {'id': 2,
   'info': {'somedata': 'eggspam',
            'moredata': 'eggspmtoo'}}]
```

Обычным открытием файла и созданием экземпляра `DataFrame` из `pandas` я получаю колонки `id` и `info`.

Мне нужно спарсить JSON так, чтобы вместо `info` была колонка со всем что внутри, не пойму как это сделать.

Сейчас использую такой код:

```
import json
from pandas import DataFrame
path = 'somefile.json'
with open(path, encoding='utf8') as my_file:
    info = json.load(my_file)
frame = DataFrame(info)
```

Нужного результата я не получаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pandas.io.json.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
path = 'somefile.json'
with open(path, encoding='utf8') as my_file:
    data = json.load(my_file)
```

---

Вариант 1:

```
In [131]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
Out[131]:
   id info.moredata info.somedata
0   1    spameggtoo       spamegg
1   2     eggspmtoo       eggspam
```

Вариант 2:

```
In [135]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'info', ['id'])
Out[135]:
          0  id
0  somedata   1
1  moredata   1
2  somedata   2
3  moredata   2
```